# Outlook Conversation Indexes

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am using Outlook-Redemption to manipulate the Conversation Topics of email items in order to group together emails that have different Subjects.
Would there be any bad consequences of setting all the Conversation Indexes of a batch of emails to be the same value?

Answer (score 0):

You will not see hierarchical structure, what you will see is a flat list.

Comment: I have changed my code just to duplicate the first 22 characters and that seems to be working well. Any comments?

Comment: If that is what you want, why not? :-)